# Camel route multiple if condition

Tags: apache-camel

I have to write to multiple if condition in camel and I need help to go around.

```
if(token is NULL)
if(condition is NULL) 
if(Dates does not match)
Then execute this...
```

What I am trying is

```
.choice
.when(token is NULL)
.when(condition is NULL)
.when(Dates does not match)
.log(update DB)
.endchoice()
```

which dont work.. 
Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use `Predicate`s.

You can define `Predicate`s as private field if you are using Java DSL, by using expression builder, to build multiple conditions, then use the predicate in your `when()`, your route would looks much cleaner and easier to read.

```java
private static final Predicate invalidHeaders = or(header(XXX).isNull(), header(YYY).isNull());

...

.when(invalidHeaders)
```

Answer (score 10):

Two conditions:

```java
Predicate p1 = header("token").isEqualTo("001"):
Predicate p2 = header("condition").isEqualTo("002");
```

Combine these conditions:

```java
Predicate cond = PredicateBuilder.and(p1, p2);
```

Then In Camel:

```java
.choice
.when(cond)
.log(update DB)
.endchoice()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in a single when and use and `&&`

```
.when(token is NULL && condition is NULL && XXX)
```

There are various ways to do this.

If you use Java code then you can append multiple predicates together: http://www.davsclaus.com/2009/02/apache-camel-and-using-compound.html