# How to use in operator in camel simple xml dsl?

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-blueprint

I am using Camel 2.17.0. I have a need to use in operator in the simple language in the blueprint.xml file as the following

`<choice id="_choice3">
                        <when id="_when3">
                            <simple>${header.STATUS} in 'Draft,Review'</simple>
                            ......`
However, It doesn't work and throws following exception:

org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-A5668784-61983-1579873128661-9-6]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1706)
    at org.apache.camel.builder.SimpleBuilder.createPredicate(SimpleBuilder.java:104)
    at org.apache.camel.builder.SimpleBuilder.matches(SimpleBuilder.java:83)

By the way, I have been using choice/when condition for a long time. Then I tried to use || and or operator as followings:

```
<simple>(${header.STATUS.contains("Draft")} or ${header.STATUS.contains("Review")})</simple>
<simple>(${header.STATUS} contains 'Draft' || ${header.STATUS} contains 'Review')</simple>
<simple>(${header.STATUS} contains 'Draft' or ${header.STATUS} contains 'Review')</simple>
```

In all cases, it throws the same exception. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172194/camel-route-multiple-if-condition) gets you closest but requires that you do this in Java.  Can you not leverage the Java DSL for this?

Comment: We have been using xml DSL for over two years. We are not planned to use Java

Answer (score 0):

you might lose those extra "()" (brackets) at the end.
Could you try something like this

```
<simple>${header.STATUS} contains'Draft' or ${header.STATUS} contains 'Review'</simple>
```

I pre-assume that you are setting the Draft (String) value in the Header.

I hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Yes, I set the Draft (String) value in the Header. I decided to follow an alternative approach by moving the or logic to a processor. It is good for my case.